# Cambiar de posición un objeto c# Script

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy haciendo un videojuego 2D en unity. El juego es un runner, y quiero que cada vez que toque un obstaculo mi personaje, se haga un poco hacia atrás.

Ya he buscado como cambiar de posición determinada (en este caso hacia atrás) un sprite pero no consigo encontrar la manera.

Comment: y si lo haces con el colisionador del objecto  y  cada vez que tengas una colisión cambias  la posición del  transfor un poco hacia atrás, además agrega el código que tengas para que sea mas facíl ayudarte

Comment: No estoy usando colisionadires,  estoy usando un script de un asset y un character controller, aún estoy aprendiendo Unity así que no se a que te refieres con meter el código, me imagiho que te refieres a los de los scripts. [Imagen aquí] (https://image.ibb.co/jjZ1hm/Sin_t_tulo.png)

Comment: mira esto es un tutorial     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgtQe33XBjI que me ayudo mucho cuando tuve que realizar un runner

Comment: tiene que colocar colisionadores para que lo objetos no sea intangibles   y  pueda tocarse como se ve la imagen del link https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1hgkyf14hwY/maxresdefault.jpg espero que te ayude la informacion que te brinde

Comment: y si coloca los scripts que tengas o como lo estas haciendo para que se toque  te recomiendo buscar sobre colisionadores y  sobre como manejar el tranfor que es que le da la posicion del personaje

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes restar las unidades que desees al transform del personaje.
ejemplo:

```
Vector3 pos = transform.position;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
  if(other.collider.compareTag("Obstacle"))
  {
    pos.x -= 1;                             //Se le resta una unidad al personaje en el eje x
  }
}
```